# how can I tell if mysql_real_escape_string is working

Tags: php, mysql

As it says in the title , how can I tell if the mysql_real_escape_string is working how it should without waiting to be hacked ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the values you get back from it.

Send it some text that it should escape, such as `Ed O'Neil` (Which should come back as `Ed O''Neil` or `Ed O\'Neil`)

Comment: Would this be ok then ? 

$post = $_GET['post'];
 
 if(is_numeric($post))
 {
  $post = mysql_real_escape_string($post);
 }
 else
 {
  die("NAUGHTY NAUGHTY");
 }
 
 mysql_select_db("*******", $******);
 
 $content = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_***** WHERE Id='" . $post . "'");

Comment: It seems to me that if is_numeric($post) is true, $post wouldn't need to be escaped as it's already a number.  Still, it can't hurt to double-check.

Comment: If i expect a numeric value i usually just use "SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz=" . (int)$foo; If the value is not a number it returns 0, resulting in (usually, depending on query) an empty result set and any other number will be stripped of all non-numerical characters (see behaviour of integer casts in the manual). For inserts/updates there has to be validation though as 0 might not always be ok. Advantage is: Much shorter than escaping and makes it clear for others reading the code that it's a number. About speed: Not sure there but i think it might be faster than escaping.

Answer (score 1):

Create a unit test that sends it all characters it should escape and checks it output.

BUT:
Why don't you simply use parameterized queries with PDO?
Like:

```
$dbh = new PDO([...]);
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz=:baz");
$sth->execute(array(":baz" => $mybaz));
```

It is the safest way and thanks to PDO it's nearly as easy as in Perl.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on what 'R. Bemrose' offered, here is some sample code to do just that. Be sure to replace the mysql credentials with your own.

```
<?php
// Connect
$link = mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')
    OR die(mysql_error());

$user = "Ed O'Neil";
$password = "SQL_INJECTION ';'alter table xyz';";

// Query
$query_safe= sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='%s' AND password='%s'",
            mysql_real_escape_string($user),
            mysql_real_escape_string($password));

// Query
$query_not_safe= sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='%s' AND password='%s'",
            $user,
            $password);

echo $query_safe."\n";
echo $query_not_safe;

?>
```